# Publishing android app error: You need to use a different package name because "com.xxxx" already exists in Google Play

Tags: android, react-native

I use react-native to make an app, upload apk on play store, and get this issue:
Publishing android app error: You need to use a different package name because "com.xxxx" already exists in Google Play.

My package name it is also connected to google-services.jason(firebase analytics and AdMob).

How properly change package name?

Comment: You must change your app package name and also on "google-services.json" too

Comment: only this part? "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.xxxx"
        }

Comment: No, again download google-services.json with new package name

Comment: I need add a new app for android in firebase console and download google-services.json, old app delete?

Comment: Yes exactly this is the way

Comment: Why the hell is google (which owns firebase) not validating their firebase bundle ids with google play. It could prevent duplicate names and issues like this. I need also to change my bundle id... disappointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need to assign a new/unique bundle identifier to your app. For that you will have to make changes to:

- **applicationId** in (*/android/app/build.gradle file*)
- **package** in (*/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*)
- and other files with Package ID

But I would suggest you to use the package [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) which will safely update the App and Package name as well.

For firebase (google-services.json), you will need to configure another app with newly created bundle id and then attach the updated .json file to the project.

Comment: @Ismeet if you have find it helpful, an Upvote would be much appreciated :)